# Flutter - Dropdown - Items - Disable?

Tags: flutter

I discovered the DropdownButton Widget in Flutter and I played around with the items.My question is now, why is there no option to disable an item in the dropdownmenuitem widget? Or is there a way to do it?

My Idea was that I have multiple dropdowns with the same itemList and if I choose one item in an dropdown it should be disabled in the other ones. Any Idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://dartpad.dev/d2b1688b14270bdf56ae952adfac93d2

there is no official way to disable some `DropdownMenuItem` but you can simulate this by not selecting the disabled item when selected and by changing its color.
otherwise, you would need to copy `DropdownButton` and add this capability yourself.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final disabledItems  = ['Free', 'Four'];

  String dropdownValue = 'One';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String newValue) {
        if (!disabledItems.contains(newValue)) {
          setState(() {
            dropdownValue = newValue;
          });
        }
      },
      items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(
            value,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: disabledItems.contains(value) ? Colors.grey : null,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's good.. but it's hard to do it with mulitple dropdowns right?

Comment: no, it's not hard, I will edit the example of how to do it.

Comment: set onChanged: null for disabling

Comment: This answer is wrong/old, see @david's answer and use `enabled: false`

Answer (score 3):

Just try this:

```dart
return DropdownButtonFormField(
      value: dropValue,
      items: DropItems.map((String value) {
        if (value == "a") {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            child: Text(value, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
            value: value,
            onTap: () => null,
            enabled: false, // disable this item
          );
        }
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(child: Text(value), value: value);
      }).toList(),
      onTap: (){
           // some code
      },
      onChanged: (){
           // some code
      },
    );
)
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different version:

Creates all the items, but the ones which must be disabled have onTap => null && Color = grey.

You can merge this solution with @humazed's, to check if an element is contained inside an exclusion list.

```dart
String selectedValue;

...

 DropdownButtonFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.category),
                labelText: 'Disabled dropdown menu'),
            items: ['a', 'b', 'c'].map((value) {
              // normal options
              if (value != 'c') {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value,
                      style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                );
              // the disabled one ("c") 
              } else {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  child: Text(value, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                  onTap: () => null,
                );
              }
            }).toList(),
            value: selectedValue,
            onChanged: (String newValue) {
              setState(() {
                selectedValue = newValue;
              });
            },
          ),
```

Wouldn't be nice to set onTap() => null and have the menu option already disabled? Like a disabled button works. I've sent an improvement request on Flutter's github